# Visual Studio Online CI daily builds fail since switching to VS 2015 and using C# 6 Roslyn features

Tags: c#, tfsbuild, azure-devops, c#-6.0

Since switching from `VS 2013` to `VS 2015` and using some new `C# 6` features, our daily builds in `Visual Studio Online` have begun failing.

The errors on the build are all pointing to the new auto property feature but I assume all new features will cause this.

An example piece of code that causes a failure is using:

```
public int MyFavouriteNumber { get; set; } = 7;
```

instead of

```
private int _myFavouriteNumber = 7;
public int MyFavouriteNumber 
    { 
        get { return _myFavouriteNumber; } 
        set { _myFavouriteNumber = value; } 
    }
```

I've had a look around my build configuration, but I can't see anything that relates to `C# 6` or `Roslyn`.

What do I have to change to make my daily builds work again?

**Edit**

Here's an example error (they're all the same, for auto properties).

> Models\Core\Bookings\BookingProduct.cs (29, 0)
>   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> Models\Core\Bookings\BookingProduct.cs (29, 0)
>   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

And here is the offending line:

```
public virtual IList<BookingPricingAddon> AddonsPricing { get; set; } = new List<BookingPricingAddon>();
```

Comment: Please provide the errors, otherwise it will all be guesswork

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I already showed the cause of the error. But I've updated my answer with the error and what is in the code on the line it states.

Comment: daft question but are you building it with c# 6?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TheLethalCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4631427/thelethalcoder)'s comments pointed me in the right direction.

The problem was that all of my projects were using `Default` as the target Language Version, which is fine if you're using `VS 2015`, however, my `.sln` file had the following opening 3 lines:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.31101.0
```

Apparently, `Visual Studio Online` uses this to work out which version of `MSBuild` to use. (It was using `12`).

Upgrading my solution to the following:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0
```

allowed `Visual Studio Online` to see that my IDE was using Roslyn, and therefore used `MSBuild 14`.

The easiest way I found to upgrade is to click on the solution in `Solution Explorer` and then going to `File > Save As > Solution File` and overwrite your existing solution file, it just upgrades the first 3 lines.

My builds are now successful.

I think the same could be achieved by setting the `Language Version` on each of your projects. This can be done by going to your `.csproj` files and navigating to:

```
Properties > Build > Advanced > Language Version > C# 6.0
```

A good reference about the `Default` settings in each IDE can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St).

> [image: Default compilers for each IDE.]